# After RStudio upgrade, styler's style_selection function not working

Tags: r, rstudio, r-styler

After upgrading RStudio in Ubuntu **22.04.1** (via `rstudio-2022.12.0-353-amd64.deb` available at https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/) the function `style_selection` that is part of the `styler` package has stopped working for me. The problem appeared while I was running `styler` version **1.7.0** - after upgrading to current version **1.8.1**, the problem described below persisted. I'm running R version **4.1.2**.

It seems that, in contrast to typical R packages, `styler` is a part of RStudio via Addins - for reference, in RStudio, clicks **Tools**, then **Addins**, then **Browse Addins**, and then **Keyboard Shortcuts**. Take note of the shortcut for the Addin named **Style Selection** - mine is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (this is possibly the default, but not certain).

Minimal example:

```
library(styler)
2+2 # take note of spacing
```

Highlight the above code and then hit the shortcut for **Style Selection** which for me is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. Expected result:

```
library(styler)
2 + 2 # take note of spacing
```

Instead of expected result, I receive the following error message:

```
> styler:::style_selection()
Using style transformers `styler::tidyverse_style()`
Error in `styler:::style_selection()`:
! No code selected
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

(Running `rlang::last_error()` and `rlang::last_trace()` don't seem to return anything meaningful.)

Any ideas? Thank you.

---

Update: Downgrading to `rstudio-2022.07.2-576-amd64.deb` resolves the problem. However, running the current version would be preferred.

Comment: This seems like you should be filing a bug report with the package author: https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues

Comment: Ive just try it in RStudio 2022.12.0 Build 353 for Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) and it seem to work... Are you using Ubuntu 18+?

Comment: Noted, thanks for checking. Yes, I'm running **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS**.

Comment: Intriguing.... Im running R version 4.2.2, styler 1.8.1, in Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.. What could it be?

Comment: For reference, I'm running R version **4.1.2**. I'd upgrade to test, but I'm in the middle of a project and can't make any changes. When done with the project, I'll do the upgrade. Thanks for the detailed info.

Comment: Ive dowgraded to R 4.1.2, and it also seems to work....